# Edge IE Mode - Local Group Policy

Tags: internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I figured out how to set Local Group Policy for my own local testing...via gpedit...

Local Computer Policy --> Administrative Templates --> Microsoft Edge

1. Configure Internet Explorer Integration

Click Enabled

Under Options - select Internet Explorer mode

2. Configure the Enterprise Mode Site List

Click Enabled

Under Options - enter file:////c:/my_sites/sites.xml

3. This is from c:/my_sites/sites.xml

site url - "www.google.com"

compat-mode - default

open-in -IE11

site url - "internal001.here.com"

compat-mode - default

open-in - IE11

However, I've been trying all day and nothing seems to take. Edge just opens google and that internal001 site in Edge. Do you guys have any ideas what could be blocking or missing? Thank you.

Comment: When I enable "Send all intranet sites to Internet Explorer", that works. So it's something with the Enterprise Mode Site List. Whether I place sites.xml on the local c:/ somewhere or on //network, nothing takes.

Comment: Could you please run `edge://compat/iediagnostic` in Edge and provide the screenshot of the result? How do you set your **sites.xml** file? My file is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zITVJ.png) and it works. The value I enter in the group policy options is like this: `file:///D:/testsite.xml`. Besides, don't forget to run `gpupdate /force` in cmd to make the group policy work.

Comment: Hi. Here is a screenshot of edge://compat/iediagnostic... https://ibb.co/YDHyw7d. Is the file:////c:fec_api/sites.xml link supposed to be active? Clicking on it does nothing. Maybe a drive access thing? I cna't figure it out. I tried listing the site explicity in the Internet Properties - Intranet Zone but that does nothing.

Comment: https://ibb.co/0sjNvrK  ....sites.xml. Straight-forward.

Comment: Your setting seems right. I try to edit my site.xml and update the group policy, but in Edge it still shows the sites in IE mode according to the old xml file. Then I clear Edge cache running `edge://settings/clearBrowserData` and try again, it works with the new xml file. I suggest that you can also try to clear Edge cache and run again to see if the IE mode can work.

Comment: From your last comment, it seems that you have solved the issue with Enterprise Site Manager v2. If so, you can post your solution as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Yes, I will do that. I have another question if you don't mind. When updating the site list, either via notepad or through Enterprise Site Manager v2, is there something I can do to make the updates propagate automatically to client Edge browsers? It seems the list is cached or something. I read about a headers ofr HTML but nothing to put inside a Site List xml. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't find other ways to make the updates propagate automatically to Edge. You can try to reboot the computer to see if it can make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the Enterprise Site Manager v2 and created the XML through the tool and it works, for whatever reason. Before I copied and pasted into notepad and plugged in my sites. I am going to mess with this, maybe try the manual XML again with the  info from v2, see if that takes. i am also going to run the clear cache as I need to add and remove sites while I test.